# como listar archivos en python en orden por creacion o modificacion

Tags: python, archivo, os

> ***E intentado y este es el mas cercano a la realidad pero me falta ordenarlo por fecha u otro tipo de orden.***

> Aquí utilizo la librería de os con scandir pero no encuentro opciones de ordenar la lista que me devuelve todo me da error, quien me puede ayudar si tiene una mejor idea o una mejor libreria.

```py
try:
        ejemplo_dir = "./static/files/"
        with scandir(ejemplo_dir) as ficheros:
            ficheros = [fichero.name for fichero in ficheros if fichero.is_file()]
        print(ficheros)
                
        ver_url = "listar.html"
        return templates.TemplateResponse("listar.html", {
        "request": request,
        "ficheros": ficheros
        })


    except FileNotFoundError:
        return JSONResponse(content={
            "list": False,
            "message": "File not found"
        }, status_code=404)
```

Comment: Probaste con la función built-in sorted?

Answer (score 0):

Una forma es creando una lista bidimencional con 2 elementos por fila: el primero es el nombre del archivo y el segundo será "el cálculo" (nombre, tamaño, modificación, etc...).
Finalmente se [ordena la lista](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20099713/1545868) (ascendente o descendente) basado en ese segundo elemento, por ejemplo:

```py
>>> data = [['file1','cr03'], ['file2','cr01'], ['file3','cr02']]
>>> sort_by_value = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=False)
>>> print(sort_by_value)
[['file2', 'cr01'], ['file3', 'cr02'], ['file1', 'cr03']]
```

Aplicando el concepto:

```py
import os

def list_files(dir_src, sortype='name', desc=False)->list:
    sort_fn = { 'name':os.path.basename, 'size': os.path.getsize, 
    'created':os.path.getctime, 'modified':os.path.getmtime 
    }[sortype]
    res = []
    for file_obj in os.scandir(dir_src):
        if file_obj.is_file():
            fname = file_obj.name
            res.append([fname, sort_fn(os.path.join(dir_src, fname))])
    res = sorted(res, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=desc)
    return [x[0] for x in res]
```

Ahora lo puedes emplear en tu desarrollo:

```py
ejemplo_dir = "./static/files/"
ficheros = list_files(ejemplo_dir, sortype='modified', desc=False)
```

Puedes usar como argumento, `sortype='name'`, `'size'`, `'created'` o `'modified'`. Y `desc=True` (ascendente) o `False` (descendente).